# How to apply multiple validators to a single paper-input in Polymer

Tags: validation, polymer

I am building a polymer application and I have to form/input validation.

How do I apply multiple validators to a single `paper-input`?

In documentation it is say that one needs to provide a validator and a message validation in their respective field.

But what if I want to apply multiple validations and messages depending on what the user writes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your use-case is not supported by default but you can achieve it by designing the validator to the `paper-input` as a facade for multiple validators, and then have an `errroMessage` at is interface that you bind to the `paper-input` own `errorMessage`, so that the validation message will change depending on your validation.
It would look like:

```
<my-validator error-message="{{errMsg}}"><my-validator>
<paper-input validator="my-validator" error-message="{{errMsg}}"><paper-input>
```

I hope you get the idea, I can help further if you start with a JSBIN or Plunkr!

Comment: Thank you and yes, that was I thinking. I would like a response from polymer team to know if it is plan a day to improve this "weakness"

Comment: you won't get an answer from the Polymer team here, if you want, you can raise an issue on GH and then discuss the topic.